# how to load script file available in one folder up than the loading html file

Tags: javascript, html

I am kind of new to web development..so not sure if this is possible, 
I am trying to load a script file from HTML file. Script file is available one folder up than the html

/test/myScript.js

/test/test123/MyPage.html

I am trying to load myscript.js file using following..but its not working. let me know how to proceed further on this.

```
 <script src="../test/myScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have an emtpy web project from visual studio, this html file is added there. when i run the solution this file start on IISExpress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove test from the path.

Try this.

```
<script src="../myScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Make sure script file is also added to visual studio project.

> > **HINT** : You can also drag script file to the HTML editor in visual studio. It would have created script tag with path for you. Not sure which visual studio you are using but almost all VS support this.

Comment: So Draging that on editor does not work or script tag does not worked?

Comment: dragging on editor just opens the file in new window

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong. Open html file. Select js file from solution explorer and drag it on html file that you recently opened. I have performed with vs 2013 and it worked correctly for me.

Comment: yes..that did work..my script file was outside and i was just dragging it from outside..i included that in vs and then dragged, so it worked.